# CSS is not loading in Rails 4.2.5 | development environment

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4

Gone through some of the solutions and included the below in my `development.rb` file

```
config.assets.precompile = true  
config.assets.precompile =  ['*.js', '*.css', '*.css.erb']
```

Still facing the same issue. Can anybody help here?

Here is the snapshot of `application.css` file

```
/*
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

I am trying to load the css in `register.html.erb` whose contents are

```
<h1>Register#register</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/register/register.html.erb</p>
```

and the style sheet I am trying to load is `style_pub.css`

```
h1 {
  color : green;
}
```

Console log error:

```
Started GET "/stylesheets/assets/stylesheets/application.css" for ::1 at 2016-08-06 17:17:43 +0530

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/assets/stylesheets/application.css"):
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20
```

`application.html.erb` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>CssTest</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'assets/stylesheets/application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'assets/javascripts/application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

New error log after the suggested change:

```
Started GET "/register/register" for ::1 at 2016-08-06 17:46:41 +0530
Processing by RegisterController#register as HTML
  Rendered register/register.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 384ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method):
    2: <html>
    3: <head>
    4:   <title>CssTest</title>
    5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    6:   <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    8: </head>
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___978862768_58522776'
```

Comment: add the `code` of `application.css`

Comment: what kind of `css` you have written and not loading?

Comment: Just a simple color change of `h1` tag. Even that is not loading. BTW I have added that in my public folder.

Comment: then how can it load? Move that `css` file to `app/assets/stylesheets/` it will resolved your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your `css` files from `public` directory to `app/assets/stylesheets/` directory, it will resolved your problem.

By `*= require_tree .` line of code in `application.css` includes all `css` files within `app/assets/stylesheets/` directory.

replace your below lines
from

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'assets/stylesheets/application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'assets/javascripts/application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

to

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

it will works fine

Comment: I moved the file to that folder. Still no luck. I checked the console log. It says could not get the css file because of routing error(No matches /application.css).

Comment: `<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>` is this line in your `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` file?

Comment: That was giving me `ActionView::Template::Error (TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method):` error. So I changed that to relative path

Comment: which `rails` and `ruby` version you used?

Comment: Rails 4.2.5.1 and ruby 2.2.4

Comment: add the all details like in which file you trying to load the css and which layout you used

Comment: it should works if your `style_pub.css` is in `app/assets/stylesheets/`

Comment: I appreciate your help your help. But it is not working. Added some more info.

Comment: `"/stylesheets/assets/stylesheets/application.css")` is incorrect

Comment: I get that but I am getting another error like I said in my second comment.

Comment: until you not provide this details I can't help you

Comment: what else is required?

Comment: will let you know based on that if required

Comment: Just in case you are missing anything, you have `application.css`, `register.html.erb`, `style_pub.css`, console log, `application.html.erb` files above. Let me know if anything else is required.

Comment: here you go, remove relative path from both tags. `stylesheet_link_tag` and `javascript_include_tag`

Comment: it should be like this `<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'assets/stylesheets/application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'assets/javascripts/application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
`

Comment: Clone [this repo](https://github.com/hgsongra/sample-demo) and compare it with your code

Comment: will do. But are you using Windows or Linux? If linux which flavour?

Answer (score 0):

**This must work for you**

Please add your stylesheet to application.css file in app/assets/stylesheet folder.

```
/*
*= require style_pub
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
*/
```

Now try restarting server if still doesn't work.

Comment: I will try this once. But, when I tried the same thing on Fedora. It worked like a charm. There seems to be a compatibility issue in case of windows.